# No se puede usar un valor de tipo "const char *" para inicializar una entidad de tipo "char *"

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Mi objetivo es poder enviar datos a un arduino por medio del puerto usb de mi computadora.

Tengo un archivo SerialPort.cpp y SerialPort.h estos son los que me ayudan a utilizar el puerto deseado, pero estos no marcan ningun error.

Tambien tengo un archivo Main.cpp que es donde marca el error al momento de declarar mi variable "port":

```
char output[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
char *port = "\\\\.\\COM6"; //Linea donde marca el error
char incoming[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"\\\\.\\COM6"` es un literal de texto, por ello es invariable y precisamente por eso sólo puede ser apuntado por punteros constantes:

```
   const char *port = "\\\\.\\COM6";
// ~~~~~ <--- Puntero constante.
```

---

Un literal es un valor que está representado en el código de manera directa; por ejemplo: todos los números son literales, `nullptr` es el literal de puntero nulo,  `true` o `false` son los literales de valores booleanos y `'c'` es un literal de caracter.

Un literal por su naturaleza, no puede cambiar de valor; el literal `42` es exactamente el mismo en cualquier parte del código en que lo escribas, es indistinguible un `42` de cualquier otro `42` y si fuese posible cambiar su valor ¡ya no sería `42`! es por esto que los literales son de manera natural: constantes e invariables.

El lenguaje C++ es un [lenguaje de tipado fuerte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_fuerte), por lo que todos los datos tienen un tipo concreto y este tipo no puede variar. El tipo de los literales de texto es `const char[tamaño]`. Concretamente el tipo del literal `"\\\\.\\COM6"` es `const char[9]` y por ello, si quieres apuntar a esos datos, el puntero debe ser constante.